# Adding space between words in Bootstrap 3.0 (HTML escape characters do not work)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Stackoverflow, please help!

I am developing a website using Bootstrap (3.1.1) and AngularJS for my friend's photography business.

The problem which I am encountering arises when trying to add a tab-space between words in the navigation bar, for example:

```
<a href="#/" class="navbar-brand">JOHN &#9;&#9; DOE</a>
```

The only way in which I have been able to get this to work is by using `<pre>` tags, but this results in a completely different styling to that which is desired.

I have tried with and without using the AngularJS `$Sanitize` module, which had no affect.

I think I am missing something fundamental but I am obviously unsure as to what that is.

Thanks in advance,

JohnDoe

Comment: Why not use a span and define it in a class for the span?

Comment: Worth noting, I am not a well experienced front-end developer.

Comment: @Aibrean thanks for the super speedy response, could you provide a simple expample? I've tried using span tags, surrounding each of the words which I want "spaced" apart.

Comment: @Aibrean for example: <span>john</span> &#9; <span>doe</span>

Comment: I've created an example here using Aibrean's suggestion: [http://www.bootply.com/XdMAHtNjNZ](http://www.bootply.com/XdMAHtNjNZ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a span would provide much cleaner code.

`<a href="#/" class="navbar-brand">JOHN<span class="tab-space">DOE</span></a>`

Then the css:

`span.tab-space {padding-left:5em;}`

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rnaUK/)

Comment: That works: clean and simple. Thanks again and again! =] I will accept the answer once sufficient time has passed.

Comment: Not doubting this will look right, but doesn't this mean search engines and screen readers will see this as one word?

Comment: @rybo111 Are there any work-arounds to improve SEO with this suggested implementation? For the time being the website aims to act as an online CV to show potential employers, so SEO is not a major concern. But this is very likely to change.

Comment: @rybo111 in that event, you can just add a space before "DOE" or after "JOHN". Considering he wants the space there, "more" space isn't going to hurt ;)

Comment: @Aibrean the problem is that extra spaces seem to get removed... And like I said before, escape characters don't seem to work. Is there a reason why my chosen combination of frameworks would stop escape characters from being rendered properly?

Comment: @JohnDoe extra spaces being made by HTML numbers and actual spaces for sentence use (not an HTML nbsp, but an actual space) are two different things. You could try a combination of dave and my solutions. I am unfortunately not knowledgeable of AngularJS.

Comment: @Aibrean Thanks, I am happy with your solution for the time being.

Comment: It is possibly not clear, from my question, that John and Doe are intended to be separate words in this context.

Comment: Perhaps put the space inside a span and style that.

Comment: @rybo111 I think the problem is when he uses character entities. If it is a keyed in space (using the spacebar) it should work. The issue is when you need a larger amount of space, in which case the span is more effective. I would like to know whether the output in code view actually includes a space (if using the keyboard).

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS word spacing:

```
a.navbar-brand{
  word-spacing:5em;
}
```

Or if you only want tab spaces in certain points, use:

```
<span class="tab-space"> </span>
```

And a similar CSS:

```
span.tab-space {
  word-spacing:5em;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a clean method of getting the effect I need. I'll try this when I get round to tidying up my work.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
.navbar-brand {
{
   white-space:pre;
}
```

To make the browser not collapse whitespace.

Comment: It works on Chrome 1.0, Firefox 1.0, IE 6.0, Opera 4.0, and Safari 1.0.  What browser do you consider major that this wouldn't work in? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: I was thinking of a different syntax. Comment removed :)

Comment: @dave I would consider this to be a suitable range of targeted browsers. I am not particularly interested in the laborious task of supporting all browsers, and especially not early versions of IE.

Comment: @dave A slightly off-topic, yet related question, if I add this solution to my custom CSS file and load that after the 3rd party style sheet which I use, will this overwrite all of the other style features of .navbar-brand? (I want to keep 3rd party style sheets intact, but I'd like to add this extra style feature to my site).

Comment: @JohnDoe - if you add this custom CSS, it will overwrite ONLY the white-space CSS property of .navbar-brand, all other styles applied to it will remain intact

Answer (score 1):

When styles to websites, its best practice to separate HTML markup from the CSS stylings of the page so that the content and stylings act independently and are more easily interchangable. This being said, its not clean to use HTML entities such as `&nbsp;` to affect style because it breaks this rule.

If you want some whitespace, wrap a `<span>` tag around the text and give it some padding.

HTML:

```
<a href="#/" class="navbar-brand">JOHN <span class="space-left">DOE</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.space-left{
   padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: A good explanation of the solution provided by Aibrean's answer. Thanks for your input.